# The random symbols in strings in c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
char a[100];
long int n,i,j,k,l,sum,p,q;
while(scanf("%ld",&l))
{

    for(i=0; i<pow(10,l); i++)
    {
        if(l==2)
            sum=((i/10)+(i%10))*((i/10)+(i%10));
        else if(l==4)
            sum=((i/100)+(i%100))*((i/100)+(i%100));
        else if(l==8)
            sum=((i/10000)+(i%10000))*((i/10000)+(i%10000));
        if(sum==i)
        {
            itoa(i,a,100);
            j=strlen(a);
            for(k=0; k<l-j; k++)
                printf("0");
            for(k=0; k<j; k++)
                a[k]=a[k]+48;
            puts(a);
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

I don't understand what this output is. I am trying to find out quirksome numbers.I am a beginner.Help please.
About quirksome number:
The number 3025 has a remarkable quirk: if you split its decimal representation in two strings of equal
length (30 and 25) and square the sum of the numbers so obtained, you obtain the original number:

(30 + 25)<sup>2</sup> = 3025

Comment: This part: `for(k=0; k<j; k++) a[k]=a[k]+48;` seems to make little sense. If `a` is already a decimal integer, why are you overwriting the characters? Very confusing.

Comment: Unrelated, but you forgot  `#include <math.h>`. And don't use magic numbers such as `48` but write `'0'` instead; this is equivalent but shows clearly your intention.

Comment: ... and what output do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you got this code from somewhere else and you want to understand what it does.

It asks for `l`, which will be the length of the number. `l` must be 2, 4 or 8 (the code doesn't check this).

For each value `i` from 1 to 10 to the power of `l` it participates the number in its two parts and then performs the "quirksome" calculation into `sum`.

If the sum is equal to the current `i`, it is a quirksome number and prints it. The printing is a bit strange and forgets to teminate string `a`. (Before `puts(a);` there must be a `a[k]=0;`). The whole printing could have been done with `printf("%0*d\n",l,i);`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this code - brutforce finder. It is easy to make it much faster but I leave it for you. I have used microsoft specific functions but it easy to change it your C libraries implementation ones

```
int isQuirksome(unsigned long long number)
{
    int result = 0, len;
    char strnumber[50], first[50], second[50];


    if (number < 10ULL) result = -1;
    if (result != -1)
    {
        _ui64toa(number, strnumber, 10);  // microsoft specific use the one from your library
        len = strlen(strnumber);
        result = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++)
        {
            unsigned long long FirstValue, SecondValue, sum;

            strncpy(first, strnumber, i);
            strncpy(second, strnumber + i, len - i);
            first[i] = 0;
            second[len - i] = 0;

            FirstValue = _strtoui64(first, NULL, 10);
            SecondValue = _strtoui64(second, NULL, 10);
            sum = FirstValue + SecondValue;
            if ((sum * sum) == number)
            {
                result = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    char result[50];

    for (unsigned long long i = 10; i < ULLONG_MAX; i++)
    {
        int pos;
        if ((pos = isQuirksome(i)) > 0)
        {
            printf("Found !!!! %llu is the QuikSome Number position of the split is %d\n", i, pos);
        }
    }
}
```

and some results:

```
Found !!!! 81           is the QuikSome Number position of the split is 1
Found !!!! 100          is the QuikSome Number position of the split is 2
Found !!!! 2025                 is the QuikSome Number position of the split is 2
Found !!!! 3025                 is the QuikSome Number position of the split is 2
Found !!!! 9801                 is the QuikSome Number position of the split is 2
Found !!!! 10000                is the QuikSome Number position of the split is 3
Found !!!! 88209                is the QuikSome Number position of the split is 2
Found !!!! 494209               is the QuikSome Number position of the split is 3
Found !!!! 998001               is the QuikSome Number position of the split is 3
Found !!!! 1000000              is the QuikSome Number position of the split is 4
Found !!!! 4941729              is the QuikSome Number position of the split is 3
Found !!!! 7441984              is the QuikSome Number position of the split is 3
Found !!!! 23804641             is the QuikSome Number position of the split is 3
Found !!!! 24502500             is the QuikSome Number position of the split is 4
Found !!!! 25502500             is the QuikSome Number position of the split is 4
Found !!!! 28005264             is the QuikSome Number position of the split is 2
Found !!!! 52881984             is the QuikSome Number position of the split is 4
Found !!!! 60481729             is the QuikSome Number position of the split is 4
Found !!!! 99980001             is the QuikSome Number position of the split is 4
Found !!!! 100000000            is the QuikSome Number position of the split is 5
```